How can I target Brave or Chrome’s internal pages, e.g. chrome://settings or chrome://history, to in my manifest.json?
I have been writing browser extensions for personal use for over 14 years now, however, the changes made by browser vendors over the last 14 years have made it increasingly difficult to restyle the internal pages without writing a complete HTML document. When I first started restyling the browser pages, almost all of the browsers used to have either a userContent.css, custom.css, or reset.css that the person interested in restyling the pages could use to restyle the pages. However, based on all of my recent Bing and Google queries, I have failed to find any information on the existence of custom.css or userContent.css in modern web browser. To make it even worse, since the introduction of manifest.json file for writing custom extensions, browsers have provided no easy way to target browser’s internal pages. For example, I cannot simply write the following to target the browser’s settings page:
"content_scripts":
[ 
   {
      "matches":              ["brave://settings"],
      "css":          ["CustomCSS/BraveSettings.css"]
   }
]

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow to get some information on how to find and edit the browser’s reset or custom.css files, and the moderators marked it as already answered. They also provided a link to the question where I could find the desired information. However, the solution provided on that page is not working in my browser. Although I have tried to enable the experimental flag and it has generated the warning detailed in that answer, however, when I try to target the internal page in my manifest.json file, Brave’s manifest and extension parsing engine declines to accept my manifest.json as well formed and declines to enable the extension. I would greatly appreciate a more up-to-date and detailed information on how to target the browser’s internal pages. Can a person find and edit a CSS file that comes preinstalled with the browser?
I would also like to add that as I do not know how your question ranking and exposure works on StackOverflow, hence, kindly do not mark it as answered or read instantaneously. Most of the question available on this practical topic are more than 10 years old, and most of the answers are extremely old, as well. Browser developers have been busy retweaking their approach to how the internal pages should be targeting, and I have concluded that information provided in responses to these questions is either completely out of date or now needs additional information that would allow the information seeker to make it all work. Therefore, based on how quickly changes have taken place in the browser vendors’ approach to targeting internal pages, think about leaving it unanswered until the person who has been trying to find the information has tested all of the answers and found the correct answer.
For your information, the information provided on this page did not produce any results on my computer. Brave declines to accept the manifest.json as well formed and the extension fails.
Can you access chrome’s internal pages?
For the past couple of weeks, I have tried to find preinstalled files on the lines of custom.css or userContent.css but I have not been to find any such files in modern web browsers’ installed directories. I have also tried to enable experimental flags that are meant to allow the authors of extensions to access and restyle web browser’s internal pages. However, even that has not worked on my computer. Based on the speed with which modern browser vendors’ approaches have changed, my presumptive feeling is that they have changed this experimental flag based approach, as well.
I was hoping that I would be able to find a userContent.css or custom.css type file that would allow me to style the internal pages without having to first author a complete HTML page and find JavaScript APIs that provide access to system clock and various folders. None of it has worked so far.

Try chrome:// instead of brave:// because it's the internal URL.

@woxxom About to give it a try and will update it shortly with the results. Thanks for taking the time.

@woxxom Updated the manifest to test it using "chrome://settings" and "chrome://history". However, both Chrome and Brave declined to deem it well formed. That definitely does not appear to be the answer.

It works if you add / at the end of the URL. The example in the answer you've linked shows that too.

@woxxom When it comes to simple parsing of the manifest.json file, the addition of trailing forward slash on Brave has at least made the manifest.json parsable. However, it is still not applying the styles on the specified page. The same extension with the aforementioned manifest.json is still failing on Chrome browser; Chrome is still declining to accept it well formed. Any information on how to debug extension code on targeted pages. Barring the internal pages, I have never had a problem with targeting pages, hence, I almost zero experience of debugging extension code.

@woxxom With the trailing forward slash included, I have tried it on three different pages: history, bookmarks, and newtab. It is only changing the styles on the NewTab page. Fails to apply the newly added rules on the remaining two pages.

It works for me in Chrome, https://puu.sh/KcMvz/2a97338541.png, so the problem might be your CSS e.g. its specificity is too low or the selectors are wrong.

@woxxom Just doubled checked for  noticeable changes in the history page, and it is definitely applying the updated styles to an imperceptibly small subset of the elements displayed on the page. Nevertheless, just wanted to confirm that Brave most definitely is loading the styles information even for brave:history page. Now I will to check what exactly is wrong when it comes to remaining elements.

These pages are using custom elements, so the styles are encapsulated inside, whereas the content script only affects global styles. You'll have to use a JS content script to "break into" the shadow DOM. See https://github.com/tophf/XRayStyler

@woxxom Many, many thanks for taking the time and sharing this information. Let’s see whether I get to the JavaScript part or not. Nevertheless, my biggest concern, The New Tab page, has started to look much better after today’s work. Many thanks. It would be immensely nice of you to put all of that information together and post it as the answer.
